# How can I add IntelliJ IDEA project JDK setting to Git?

Tags: java, git, intellij-idea, java-8, corretto

A common pain point with IntelliJ IDEA is correctly configuring the JDK for each project you work on every time you clone the repository or lose the .idea folder.

I want to include the JDK settings in Git to make it easier, especially for new developers, to get up and running. We all agreed to use Coretto 1.8.

First, I added .idea/compiler.xml, which specifies the project language level:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="CompilerConfiguration">
    <bytecodeTargetLevel target="1.8" />
  </component>
</project>
```

Next, I added .idea/misc.xml, which specifies the project JDK:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ExternalStorageConfigurationManager" enabled="true" />
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" default="true" project-jdk-name="corretto-1.8" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" />
</project>
```

Then I deleted the ~/.jdks directory, cleaned the project directory with `git clean -fdx` and reopened the project in IntelliJ. It correctly restored the language level to 1.8 but downloaded Corretto 11 and changed the contents of .idea/misc.xml to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project version="4">
  <component name="ExternalStorageConfigurationManager" enabled="true" />
  <component name="ProjectRootManager" version="2" languageLevel="JDK_1_8" project-jdk-name="corretto-11" project-jdk-type="JavaSDK" />
</project>
```

Do I need to include some other file or is there some other trick?

Comment: Is this a Gradle project? Did the IDEA download the Corretto 11 automatically in your case without clicking any button notification?

Comment: @floatingcat it is a Gradle project. It only downloaded Corretto 11 once I clicked the "Import Project" button.

Comment: Looks related to this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-281903/ In general, the IDEA should not download any JDK here without asking you if agree to download and when you open a JDK file, it will ask for a notification in the editor top to ask you to download the missed JDK. It seems the IntelliJ IDEA team is working on this feature request (which could configure the JDK vendor too) and may help for your use cases: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-252328/